# Depleted batteries

Tags: probability, combinations, binomial-coefficients, factorial

*Accidentally, two depleted batteries got into a set of five batteries. To remove the two depleted batteries, the batteries are tested one by one in a random order. Let the random variable $X$ denote the number of batteries that must be tested to find the two depleted batteries. What is the probability mass function of $X$?*

**WARNING** $\rightarrow $ Do not use conditional probabilities.

If I understand correctly the text (that in my opinion is really unclear), $X$ represents the number of tests needed to find **simultaneously** the two depleted batteries. Thus, the minimum number of tests that I have to do in order to find **simultaneously** the two depleted batteries is two.

Let $V$ be the event the battery is depleted, and let $F$ be the event that the battery is not depleted.

$\mathbb{P}(VV)=\frac{2\cdot 1\cdot 3!}{5!}$ or in an alternative way $\mathbb{P}(X=2)=\frac{\binom{2}{2}\cdot 2!\cdot 1\cdot 3!}{5!}$ where:

- $5!$ is the number of ways to arrange in a random order all batteries on a row.
- $\binom{2}{2}$ means that I take two depleted batteries from the group of depleted batteries. And with $2!$ I arranged them (ie to say $i_1i_2$ or $i_2i_1$).
- $1$ is the number of cases in which the couple can be located on the row of two tests ($\rightarrow$ 1 case)
- $3!$ is the number of ways to arrange the other batteries.

So far, so good: the two probabilities are equal.

$\mathbb{P}[(FVV)\cup (VVF)\cup (VFV)]=\frac{3\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 2!+2\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 2!+2\cdot 3\cdot 1\cdot 2!}{5!}$ or $\mathbb{P}(X=3)=\frac{\binom{2}{2}\cdot 2!\cdot 2\cdot \binom{3}{1}\cdot 1!\cdot 2\cdot 2!+\binom{2}{2}\cdot 2!\cdot 1\cdot \binom{3}{1}\cdot 1!\cdot 1\cdot 2!}{5!}$ where

for the first addend

- $\binom{2}{2}$ means that I take two depleted batteries from the group of depleted batteries. And with $2!$ I arranged them (ie to say $i_2i_3$ or $i_1i_2$).
- $2$ is the number of cases in which the couple can be located on the row of three tests (at the right and left end of the row $\rightarrow$ 2 cases)
- $\binom{3}{1}$ means that I take one charged battery from the group of charged batteries. And with $1!$ I arranged it (ie to say $i_1$ or $i_3$).
- $2$ is the number of cases in which the charged battery can be located on the row of three tests (at the left and right end of the row $\rightarrow$ 2 cases)
- $2!$ is the number of ways to arrange the other batteries.

and for the second addend

- $\binom{2}{2}$ means that I take two depleted battery from the group of depleted batteries. And with $2!$ I arranged them (ie to say $i_1i_3$ and $i_3i_1$).
- $1$ is the number of cases in which the depleted batteries can be located on the row of three tests (at the left and right end of the row $\rightarrow$ 1 case)
- $\binom{3}{1}$ means that I take one charged battery from the group of charged batteries. And with $1!$ I arranged it (ie to say $i_2$).
- $1$ is the number of cases in which the charged battery can be located on the row of three tests (in the middle of the row $\rightarrow$ 1 cases)
- $2!$ is the number of ways to arrange the other batteries.

Unfortunately, in this case, the first probability is $\frac{3}{10}$ and the second is $\frac{1}{2}$: why?

Comment: The question can also be read as saying there are 5 good batteries, with 2 bad ones dropped into the box with them.

Comment: @Peter Oh, simply $\operatorname{IpGeo}\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X=3)=\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{5-2}{3-2}}{\binom{5}{3}}$. However I would like to understand where I'm doing wrong in that case (factorials and binomial coefficients).

Comment: I read the problem as you test the batteries in order until you have found the 2 bad ones. Note the max number of tests is 5. For 1 test P=0. For 5 or less P=1. For 4 or less the last must be good, so P = 3/5. For 3 or less the last 2 must be good, so P = 3/5 * 2/4 = 3/10, thus for exactly 4, P = 3/5 - 3/10 = 3/10. And so on. But maybe for 2 tests it should be 2/7 * 1/6 (if there are 7 altogether).

Comment: @Peter Sure, the probabilities are correct but my question was about the use of factorials and binomial coefficients.

Comment: In the first addend, you don't have two choices twice for the end positions. When you have used two positions for the bad batteries you can't choose a place to put a good one.

Comment: @Peter Mh, so is it $\mathbb{P}(X=3)=\frac{\binom{2}{2}\cdot 2!\cdot 2\cdot \binom{3}{1}\cdot 1!\cdot 1\cdot 2!+\binom{2}{2}\cdot 2!\cdot 1\cdot \binom{3}{1}\cdot 1!\cdot 1\cdot 2!}{5!}$? Indeed on second thought, if I have two choices for the couple of "bad" batteries, the position of good one is obliged in both cases... Right? (See the sixth factor in the first addend)

Comment: Looks right now. It is (24 + 12)/120 = 3/10 instead of (48+12)/120 = 1/2. Just note thought that if you have the 5 batteries (unmarked) on the shelf there are 10 orders to put them. If you mark the batteries each of the 10 is 2! * 3! = 12 different orders. 10 is easier to work with! Do you want this put up as an answer?